# GridView with SiteMap data source - displaying child nodes

Tags: .net, gridview, sitemap

Sitemap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0">
    <siteMapNode  url="" title="hello"  description="hello">
        <siteMapNode  url="~/WFM1.aspx" title="WFM1"  description="This is WFM1" />
        <siteMapNode url="~/WFM2.aspx" title="WFM2"  description="This is WFM2" />
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

.aspx :

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" Height="52px" style="margin-right: 2px; margin-top: 9px" Width="215px">
            <Columns >
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Title" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Url" HeaderText="Url" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Url" />
            </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
```

For some reason it only shows me the parent node. I wonder if I don't get something, but I want two childs to be shown too within the GridView. Don't ask me why I need to do it in this particular way. (I don't know either - welcome to academia)

context: VS2012:U

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am simplifying your code, but why not nest a Gridview control, using the ChildNodes as a Datasource? You can also do this in a Repeater if that serves your purpose better.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" Height="52px" style="margin-right: 2px; margin-top: 9px" Width="215px">
    <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" DataSource='<%#Eval("ChildNodes")%>'></asp:GridView>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```